# Eclipse Birt - How to make a column completely invisible in Excel output

Tags: excel, eclipse, tableau-api, birt

Eclipse Birt - How to make a column completely invisible in Excel output

I need to make the first column invisible of a table/cross tab completely invisible on the output (but it cannot be deleted)

I have tried:

1. Set it to "No Display"
2. Hide Element
3. Set width of the column to zero

In PDF, there is no issues. But in Excel, the table/cross tab will start from Column B.

Is there a way to make it completely invisible so the table/cross tab start from Column A.

Answer (score 0):

hi i don't know if you try to make the column invisible or not. I show you an example and i hope it would be helpful . I have a table in its detail part I have  a grid and I want to make the first column invisible, as you can see in picture i select that cell and select  from properties editor the visibility part then check the hide element and you can enter your circumstances in the "expression" part.[image: example of using visibility property]

Answer (score 0):

Select the column on the table and on properties go to "Visibility -> Hide Element -> For specific outputs...". Here you'll get a list of output formats where you can select whether to hide this column always, or conditionally based on some expression.

This should do the trick!